# Which of formulas for probability are correct?

Tags: probability

Which one's are true formulas for probability?

I think C is wrong, what about a) and b)

a)  $A1,A2,..,An.  p(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}Ai)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}p(Ai)$

b )$A1,A2,...  p(\bigcup_{\infty}^{n}Ai)\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}p(Ai)$

c) $B\subset A$     so $p(A\setminus B)=p(A)-p(B)$

d) $p(A\cup B)=p(A)-p(B)+p(A)P(B)$

Comment: a)  is  false.  c) is true. What exactly is the  union on the left side of b)?

Comment: I corrected C), I think it should be false?

Comment: C seems true to me, but perhaps I am misinterpreting it.  Please provide a counter-example to support your conjecture that C is not (in general) true.

Comment: It is correct because $p(A)=p(A \setminus B) +p(B)$ by additivity.

Comment: c) has comment to it "for whatever occurence"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A is true if the event are disjointed. In general

$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

C) if with P(A \ B) you mean the set difference $=P(A \cap \overline{B})$ its correct. (Do a drawing to verify it)

Comment: c) is also true?

Comment: d) $p(A\cup B)=p(A)-p(B)+p(A)P(B)$ this would be true if "+" and "-" were reversed right?

Comment: @Gorosso re part d) : yes, you nailed it.  In fact, tommik's answer actually *resolves* part d).

Comment: @Gorosso : look at my edits